# Debian : Using a cron task on Docker

Tags: mysql, cron, docker, debian, docker-compose

I am using docker with docker compose on my server (debian 7.5).

I have 1 mysql container and one postgresql container for 2 applications.

When i want to create a backup of my database (for example for the database "mydb" from my mysql container) I do like this :

```
docker exec -it <my_container_id> mysqldump --opt mydb > "/backup/mydb$(date +%Y%m%dà%H%M).sql"
```

It works very well. The backup is saved in my local server.

The thing is I want to create this task everyday. So i created a file "backup.sh" in /etc/cron.daily/. (and then I did chmod +x backup.sh).

But the problem is, the cron doesn't work at all. I can see in the log that the file is executed, but I don't have anything in my backup folder.

Someone has an issue ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cron does not set the `PATH` unless you specify it.

Try with the docker absolute path (`/usr/bin/docker` most likely) in your shell script.

Comment: Same problem ( or I did it in a bad way ;-) ). if I manualy run the file that contains my command `docker exec -it <my_container_id> mysqldump --opt mydb > "/backup/mydb$(date +%Y%m%dà%H%M).sql"` it works... Still not working with con

Comment: not sure about  `-it` from a cron job, as i stands for interactive and t allocates a pty, try replacing this by `-d`

Comment: Hello @user2915097. First thank you for your help. I tried with -d. This time the cron create my .sql file, but the file is ... empty ... :-)

Comment: Anyway, i tried `/usr/bin/docker exec <my_container_id> mysqldump --opt mydb > "/backup/mydb$(date +%Y%m%dà%H%M).sql"` so without -it or -d and.... it's working very well !

Thank you everyone